# Splitting word document into separate pages using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

An hour ago I been searching for a code that split word document into separate pages I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754608/how-to-split-pages-of-a-word-document-into-separate-files-in-c-sharp)

Using the code in the thread

```
static class PagesExtension {
    public static IEnumerable<Range> Pages(this Document doc) {
        int pageCount = doc.Range().Information[WdInformation.wdNumberOfPagesInDocument];
        int pageStart = 0;
        for (int currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= pageCount; currentPageIndex++) {
            var page = doc.Range(
                pageStart
            );
            if (currentPageIndex < pageCount) {
                //page.GoTo returns a new Range object, leaving the page object unaffected
                page.End = page.GoTo(
                    What: WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage,
                    Which: WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute,
                    Count: currentPageIndex+1
                ).Start-1;
            } else {
                page.End = doc.Range().End;
            }
            pageStart = page.End + 1;
            yield return page;
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

I call the code above using this code

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object missObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
app.Visible = false;

var doc = app.Documents.Open(fileLocation);
int pageNumber = 1;

foreach (var page in doc.Pages())
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document newDoc = app.Documents.Add(ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);
    page.Copy();
    var doc2 = app.Documents.Add();
    doc2.Range().Paste();
    object newDocName = pageNumber.ToString() + ".docx";
    Console.WriteLine(newDocName);
    doc2.SaveAs2(newDocName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument,
                         CompatibilityMode: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2010);
    pageNumber++;
}
app.ActiveDocument.Close();
app.Quit();
```

But I'm getting an error in a specific document and here is the error

> This method or property is not available because no text is selected.

What is the reason for it? i checked the document and found out that the document contains lots of spaces before the next page. How can I solve this?

And using the code above it didn't copy the header and footer. Thank you

Update: Error

```
This method or property is not available because no text is selected.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.Copy()
   at retrieveObjects(String location) in Document.cs:line 31
```

and this is the line

```
page.Copy();
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @NisargShah i updated the question, Thank you. i added the complete error with the code linking in to the error

Comment: If it says you need text selected, make sure you have a range of selected text. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806763/select-page-in-docx-using-c-sharp

Comment: im sorry but i don't understand the code in the link. what does the code in the link do?